# Bash script to Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

My shell script contains below code:

```
source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh

repo project init $branch

repo project sync

source poky/fnc-init-build-env build

bitbake -g $image
```

How to convert this into python.

I tried using subprocess, os module . it does not works.

If i  I am getting "**repo command not found"**

I need some help to solve this.

Comment: If you want to check the environment variable instead of checking a constant empty string, why don’t you just check the environment variable? You clearly already know how to use `os.environ`.

Comment: if os.environ['RUN_MODE'] = " " :
        os.environ['RUN_MODE'] = "DEV"


                i tried like this    but i am getting keyvalue error

Comment: That's the same as any normal dict in Python: a key that doesn't exist doesn't have the value `" "`, it doesn't have any value at all.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. You explicitly set it with `RUN_MODE = ""`, so that's the value it's going to have. If you want to check the environment variable `RUN_MODE`, you do that using `os.environ`, exactly the same way you're already doing to set the same environment variable.

So, how do you check that an environment variable either doesn't exist, or does exist but is an empty string? The same way you do for any dict, or any other mapping, in Python: with [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
if os.environ.get("RUN_MODE", "") == "":
   os.environ["RUN_MODE"] = "DEV"
```

Also, in a comment, you were trying to test for `" "`. But `""` and `" "` are not the same string—one is empty, the other has a space in it.